# Naming all concatenated txt files

Tags: python-3.x, file, parsing, copy

I want to collect data from all .txt files into one and add name of *collected .txt name* inside this concatenated file. I try to make it with my code, but nothing. I will be grateful if you help

Source:

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt") # find all .txt files and then goes read
fileName = 'NoName' 
with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile: # create output file named result.txt
    for f in read_files:
        fileName = f
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(str(fileName) + '\n' + infile.read()) # in this line i try to add at top off collected text 'Name' of collected .txt, but i got some errors ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Rakesh TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.decode("utf-8")` and change `wb` to `w`

**Ex:**

```
import glob

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt") # find all .txt files and then goes read 
with open(filename, "w") as outfile: # create output file named result.txt
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(f + '\n' + infile.read().decode("utf-8") )
```

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 179-180: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: `with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")  as outfile:` ?

Comment: ah, i'l fixed it. All i want to do it was change to `with open("result.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")`. Thank for help! It really helps me, i forget about encoding system.